# Es posible no declarar nueva memoria para un arrray dinamico?

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria, gcc

Bien, me encontré con esto, y no se que pensar, se que para alocar memoria es necesario el operador `new` sin embargo no entiendo ¿porqué este código funciona?, y en todo caso ¿cuales son las posibles fallas? (¿tal vez es una característica de c++11 nueva que desconozco?)

```
    cout << "introduzca la capacidad ";
    cin >> capacidad;
    // como es esto posible?
    double array[capacidad];

    for (int i = 0; i < capacidad; i++){
        cout << "Numero " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >>  array[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < capacidad; i++)
        cout << "Numero " << i+1 << ": " << array[i] << "\n";
```

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double array[capacidad];
```

Esto es lo que se conoce como VLA ( Variable Length Array ). Es un array cuyo tamaño es **desconocido** en tiempo de compilación. Fíjate que su tamaño se indica mediante una variable, que es *cargada* desde `std::cin`.

Esto es **ilegal** en C++. No obstante, muchos compiladores **lo soportan como una extensión** propia del compilador que estás usando en este momento.

Puede que, al intentar compilarlo **con otro compilador**, se genere un error, si dicho compilador **no soporta** esa característica.

Comment: Entonces el problema es el compilador??!!  pero y como lo hace? como lo permite?

Comment: No es un *problema*, es una **extensión**. Es una facilidad extra que te ofrece, pero es tu decisión el usarla o no. En `gcc`, usa las opciones `-std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra`, a ver que pasa ;-)

Comment: Con `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra` obtuve `[Warning] ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'array' [-Wvla]`

Comment: Ya te está avisando: `El estándar prohibe el uso de arrays de tamaño no conocido en tiempo de compilación`. El cumple su misión. Ya es cosa tuya si *ignoras* el aviso o si cambias tu código.

Comment: Te da un aviso, y no un error, porque `gcc` **si** lo soporta. Otros compiladores, por su parte, te darán avisos, o directamente errores **si no lo soportaran**.

Comment: Sin embargo no se porque eso me parece una grosería, un crimen, o en el mejor caso una travesura de mal gusto

Comment: Es cuestión de punto de vista. La lógica seguida por `gcc` es que, si lo estás usando a él y no a otro, es, precisamente, porque **quieres** sus extensiones. Por eso las tiene activadas por defecto.